# Ways to see if address is empty

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is `owner > 0x0` a good way to test if an address `owner` was set in Solidity?
I am not sure if this could break something in the future and if there are better ways to see if the address was set. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Though this works, I personally think it is a good idea to have both operand types equal on boolean operations , as you mentioned for future compatibility.

Instead of using > operator use equality == or != , as in case of address the greater operator may not make sense.

Instead of using 0x0 use address(0) or address(0x0), as it would make much more of  type of address.

So your code would look like

```
owner==address(0);// check if the address is not set
```

Just my 2 cents

Comment: thanks, what is a Neo Noir Dev? Has it to do with Film Noir?

Comment: Is there documentation for this `address(0)` somewhere?

Comment: it merely typecasts uint 0 to an address (0x000...)

Comment: @JohnAllen as of Nov 2018, it [doesn't](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#address) seem so.

Comment: @JohnAllen it is not documented per se in the Solidity documentation, but both contracts Voting and BlindAuction mention them : https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/solidity-by-example.html?highlight=%22address(0)%22#voting